# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. for a Motorola G(7) play

Tags: android-studio

im having this error where im trying to put the app i build into my motorola g7 play and see if it works it works on the emulator so i want to see it on my phone but it doesnt install it so was wondering what can i do if anything and also want to make sure that im new so please if anything please help.

```
05/01 18:41:23: Launching 'app' on motorola moto g(7) play.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\zuper\Desktop\gif-app-master\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -S 775595832' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:467)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2730)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1106)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:176)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:22432)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:890)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:774)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4880)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4212)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1036)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1003)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:234)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:150)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:165)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:577)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:465)
... 11 more''
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

This is the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ldickmanns.gifapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ancient_architecture_building_columns"
        android:label="Egyptian Mythological Pantheon"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ancient_architecture_building_columns"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GIFApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".NUN"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HORUS"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RA"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Hathor"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ISIS"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Osiris"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Sobek"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Anubis"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the Graddle app:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ldickmanns.gifapp"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I dont know if its compatible or what to do to put it on my phone

If anything to help me put the app on my phone to test it and check that it works

Comment: "android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space"        I'm not suggesting its as simple as this, but check how much free space you have on the internal drive, not the micro-sd card we all have plugged in.